# Voltage through an inductor

Tags: capacitor, inductor

My question concerns the voltage through an inductor.

If I have a capacitor charged to a DC voltage, is it possible to discharge through an inductor, in which the voltage going into the inductor will be the same as the voltage coming out of the inductor, before it is given off to a load? Any change in current is of less concern.

I am quite new to the study of electronics, but from reading about inductors the formula for voltage is given by: v = L(di/dt). So what I imagine would happen as the capacitor discharges is that the voltage would initially jump, before falling greatly as the current steadies.

So is it possible to have the voltage coming from the capacitor the same when it reaches the load (zero change through the inductor)?

Thanks

Comment: Voltage doesn't go "through" anything. Current goes "through", voltage appears "across"

Comment: The capacitor's equation is \$I=C\:\frac{\text{d}V}{\text{d}t}\$. The inductor's equation is \$V=L\:\frac{\text{d}I}{\text{d}t}\$. There are two different ways to put them both together. One gets you the energy balance equation and the other gets you the time dependent equations of voltage and current.

Comment: Voltage will not "jump", it would only happen if the charge stored in capacitor suddenly changes by flow of sudden high current which the inductor won't allow.

Comment: Q/c = L(di/dt) and i=dq/dt  these two equations will get you differential equation in Q solution of which will be a cosine function if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Your question, and understanding of circuits, appears to suffer from imprecise language.

"Voltage" can be referred to in two ways:
1) The voltage of a node (wire) with respect to Ground is the voltage AT that node.
2) The voltage of a node with respect to another node is the voltage ACROSS a component.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzXboQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

With this in mind, lets start with a few definitions:

1) The voltage across the capacitor is the same as the voltage AT node 1
2) The voltage across the load (resistor) is the same as the voltage AT node 2
3) The voltage across the inductor is (the voltage at node 1) - (the voltage at node 2)

In the equation v = L(di/dt), v refers to the voltage across the inductor.

---

**"If I have a capacitor charged to a DC voltage, is it possible to discharge through an inductor, in which the voltage going into the inductor will be the same as the voltage coming out of the inductor, before it is given off to a load? Any change in current is of less concern."**

Lets start by assuming that the current through the load is constant.  Since v = L(di/dt) and di/dt is zero, v is also zero, so the voltage at node 1 is equal to the voltage at node 2.  If you replaced the capacitor with a constant voltage supply, this is what would actually happen.

Unfortunately, the current through the load is NOT constant, because it is discharging the capacitor.  Therefore the voltage across the inductor is not zero, and there will be different voltages at node 1 and node 2.

---

So, what would happen?  Lets assume the capacitor is initially charged to a voltage V1, and Node 2 is initially at 0V.  Then, we insert the inductor in the middle.

Rearranging the inductor equation, we get:

[image]

The inductor current was initially zero, but it can't change instantly because the voltage across it is finite, and it takes time for the integral to "build up".  Knowing exactly what happens next is more complicated because different component values will produce different behaviors, such as ringing.  Try it in the simulator and find out!

Comment: Thank you for this answer. It has cleared a lot up for me. I think as you said my understanding of voltage was imprecise.